# Why was the Obscurus omitted?

Tags: j-k-rowling

In the [Fantastic Beasts Character Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1338116789), there's a section that contains most of the animals that were shown in the movie.  However, curiously, the Obscurus is missing from the book, despite its importance to the story of the movie.

Why was the Obscurus omitted from the character guide?

Comment: Also of an important note the Obscurus is not in the original Fantastic Beasts "textbook".

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/74/are-novelizations-of-films-or-television-on-topic

Comment: meta post: http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/78/are-movie-companion-books-on-topic

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### It *is* there...

In the [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1338116789) preview of the book, on page 122 there is a chapter on *The Obscurus*.

[image: Screenshot of the table of contents. There is a chapter labeled "THE OBSCURUS" on page 122]

If you're asking why it's not included in the' beasts' section, probably because:

- It's not strictly a beast. It's the magic of a wizard that was suppressed and is *sort of* a beast.
- It's a larger topic. These things are completely new. We know nothing about them, so we need some more information.

Comment: hmm, forgot there's a specific section for the obscurus.  what I meant was the beasts section of the book.  that might be why

Comment: @DForck42 If that is what you meant, please edit the question as I think there is a relevant answer.